# Destroy class from constructor in CoffeeScript

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript

I have a base class, which is extended by multiple child classes. The base class checks some settings, to see if it should do something (kind of like an A/B-testing thing, except that half the visitors get nothing).

So if my setting is `false`, the base class should somehow delete the current object (`delete this;` doesn't work), or at least tell the child classes not to execute any more code.

The lame option, which I'd like to avoid if possible, is for the parent constructor to return `true`/`false` and have an `if` in each child constructor. I was thinking there should be an easier way to do this without adding code to the children (ideally I'd like a "double return" functionality -- return from both parent and children). Yes, no? :)

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this in the constructor? I mean, you can probably make it work, but it'll lead to some very non-intuitive (and probably error-prone) behavior. Why not write some sort of factory function so you can perform the check before even creating an instance?

Comment: The reason I can't (well, I can, but I'd have to change the whole logic), is because the constructor is the one that fetches the setting (whether or not it should do anything), so before initializing the class, I have no way of knowing if my setting is `true` or `false`.

Comment: Sounds like your constructor is doing too much work then. Refactor the settings-fetching into a separate function so you can call it from the constructor or from a factory function.

Comment: Can you add some of your code as an example? A bit hard to visualize.